# hadith source please

Tags: hadith, source-identification, reference-request

Hadith 
"This is a month (Ramadan), the first of which brings Allah's mercy, the middle of which brings His forgiveness and the last of which brings emancipation from the fire of Jahannam."

Please share the source fo this hadith

Comment: Can you share the response please from the original request?

Comment: Click on the provided link of the duplicate and you'll find your answer.